# Is there a method in leaflet that converts geographical distance (meters) to pixel distance?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to draw a circle that overlays markers within a certain distance.

I found a way to calculate a pixel to distance ratio, but just wondering if there is a more direct approach / method that returns a pixel distance given a geographical distance?

*To clarify, I want to calculate a pixel distance for the circle. (created by using L.circle)

Comment: The conversion depends on your latitude and zoom level. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Does not `L.circle` fit your needs?

Comment: I am trying to obtain a pixel distance to use it as a radius for circle (L.circle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`L.circle`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) takes a [`radius`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle-radius) option in **meters**.

[`L.circleMarker`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker) takes a [`radius`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circlemarker-radius) option in *pixels*.

Comment: yw! not _all_ screw-ups, but most of them indeed… Please do not forget to _accept_ the answer if it helped you solve your issue.